# synonym of rounding off to the nearest whole number

Tags: synonyms

Hi can you please suggest a synonym of the following sentence "rounding off to the nearest whole number"

Answer (score 2):

A rounded number can be called an approximation. You could say 34.9 is approximately 35, or the "~" symbol can be used rather than writing out "approximately" when doing math. Ex.: 34.9 = ~35.

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices:

> [round up](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/round-up) - to raise a number to the nearest whole number or ten, hundred, or thousand above it.

`2.7` rounded up is `3`

OR

> [round down](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/round-down) - to lower a number to the nearest whole number or ten, hundred, or thousand below it.

`2.7` rounded down is `2`

you can also use a [ceiling function](http://www.yourdictionary.com/ceiling-function) - which is a function that takes [real](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/numbers/definition-of-real-numbers.php) number (any number that can be put on a number line, including decimals) and maps it to the nearest whole number above it (or to the right of it when visualizing a [number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line)).

or, use a [floor function](http://www.yourdictionary.com/floor-function) - which is a function that takes a real number and maps it to the nearest whole number below it (or to the left of it when visualizing a number line).

**usages:** the floor function of `2.7` is `2` and the ceiling function of `2.7` is `3`.